# How can I share validation arrays between models?

Tags: php, validation, cakephp

For example, I have several models that have `name` and `uid` fields but some models do not have them.  I want all models that have those fields to use the following rules, however, I don't want to add the following block of code to each model.

```
public $validate = array(
    'name' => array(
        array(
            'rule' => array('between', 1, 25),
            'message' => 'Name must contain %d to %d characters',
            'required' => true
        ),
        array(
            'rule' => array('custom', AppModel::REGEX_NAME),
            'message' => 'Name contains invalid characters.'
        )
    ),
    'uid' => array(
        'rule' => 'uuid',
        'message' => 'uid is not valid.',
        'required' => true
    ), 
);
```

I've considered adding the rules to `AppModel` by setting `public $validate`.  This leads to the following problems.

1. Models without those fields always fail validation because `required` is true.
2. If you set `public $validate` in a model, it will not inherit the rules from AppModel.

I'm sure this can be handled by adding validation on-the-fly (I'm thinking beforeValidate() in AppModel) but I would like to know how others are handling this.

Does anyone know a better way?

Comment: You could use a behavior for this. http://snook.ca/archives/cakephp/multiple_validatable_behavior

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would just copy/paste the validation array in each model.

If that isn't what you want to do, you could do something like extend `AppModel` to `MyAppModel`. Within MyAppModel set `public $validate = array(...)`, and for the models needing those validation rules simply extend `MyAppModel` instead of `AppModel` in your class declaration.

As for problem #2, you need to call `parent::validate` to retrieve that array and then supplement it with further rules. My initial thought would be to create an array for the new rules not found in `MyAppModel` and then `array_merge` with that `array + parent::validate`.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually handled by just copy/pasting the validation array or setting up your "normal" validation rules into your bake template. That way, they're there by default upon starting each project.

Or per the comment above, you can use a Behavior - though unless you have a LOT of models, personally, I think that's overkill.

Answer (score 1):

1. You could add a method like mergeDefaultRules() to your AppModel that can be called from
   within each models beforeValidate() that merges the default rules
   with the model specific rules
2. You could use traits instead of using an AppModel method for that - if you can use php 5.4
3. You could use a behavior

I would go for 1 or 2.

```
// In your AppModel
public function mergeDefaultRules() {
    $this->validate = array_merge($this->validate, array(/* Default rules here */));
}
// In your specific model
public function beforeValidate($options = array()) {
    $this->mergeDefaultRules();
    return true;
}
```